# Stuck to wireframe

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image: problem]
[image: problem2]
I originally made and saved this from the latest version of blender. I don't know what comes to my mind that I tried to open,edit and save again my saved file to lower version of blender(2.60). After that,  I opened my file again to my latest ver of blender and this happened,  I cannot return the shade of my bee, it is stuck in wireframe even if I pressed  Z key several times :( and when I try to render it, I cannot see my bee object.
This is my rendered image before I messed up
[image: before the problem]

*UPDATE*
My wireframe problem is solved but the textures and materials I applied to my model is removed for some reason. As I tried to fill my model with faces. My model can only accept 1 texture/material, since I joined the model parts earlier, I cannot undo it now. I think I will just redo it again from scratch,  thanks to the people who tried to help me though

Comment: are you sure the model in edit mode its fully solid and not wire?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of it.

Comment: this is weird then, cuz you have the textured option on in display.

Comment: I think my work is now bugged/corrupted or something. I will just redo it again and never mess up this time .

Comment: Please don't write solved as part of the title... use the "accept answer" button: read: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the top of the screen you will see that the selected object has no faces.[image]

Comment: I tried to add faces but my added materials and texture is not visible for some reason.

Comment: Please update your question